# Requests suddenly not working despite no apparent change from scraping source or code

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, request, cheerio

I am currently trying to get better at scraping in JS and use request and cheerio. About two weeks ago I got a basic amazon scrape to work but this morning when I loaded my files it's no longer working. I made sure Cheerio and Request was installed on node and tried picking up requests from wikipedia and it worked fine. On Amazon my original source the code no longer works. Nothing on their webpage seems to have changed so I have no clue why none of my targets are working.

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

request(`http://amazon.com/dp/B07R7DY911`, (error,response,html) =>{
    if (!error && response.statusCode ==200) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        const productTitle = $("#productTitle").html()
        const price = $("#priceblock_ourprice").text();
        const rating = $('#centerCol #acrPopover').text().replace(/\s\s+/g, '');
        const numReviews = $('#centerCol #acrCustomerReviewText').text().replace(/\s\s+/g, '');
        const prodImg = $('#landingImage').attr('data-old-hires');

        console.log(productTitle);
        console.log(price);
        console.log(rating);
        console.log(numReviews);
        console.log(prodImg)
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
})
```

Some playing around and I get null and undefined where I simply didn't before.

Help me stack overflow. You're my only hope!

## Update:

Switched code to axios. Much better now.

```
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    axios.get(`${link}`)
      .then((response)=> {
        const html = response.data;
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    
        const productName = $("#productTitle").html().replace(/\s\s+/g, '');
        const amznPrice = $("#priceblock_ourprice").text();
        const rating = $('#centerCol #acrPopover').text().replace(/\s\s+/g, '');
        const numReviews = $('#centerCol #acrCustomerReviewText').text().replace(/\s\s+/g, '');
        const prodImg = $('#landingImage').attr('data-old-hires');
        res.render("home", {
            productTitle: productName,
            price:amznPrice,
            prod_Img:prodImg,
            azLink:links,
            });
    });
     

});
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the selectors you're using exist in the HTML you're fetching? You may not be getting the same HTML - you may be getting served a "bot verification" page in your node app (while still getting regular HTML in your regular browser) (see top related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785360/data-from-web-scraping-using-node-js-request-is-different-from-data-shown-in-the?rq=1)). I'd save the HTML received in a file, load it up in a Browser locally, then use the Developer Tools to find the relevant selectors and check if they actually exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're getting a compressed output in a format that the `request()` library does not understand.  If you add the `gzip: true` option in the `request()` call, then the code starts working for me.

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

request({url: 'http://amazon.com/dp/B07R7DY911', gzip: true}, (error,response,html) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        const productTitle = $("#productTitle").html()
        const price = $("#priceblock_ourprice").text();
        const rating = $('#centerCol #acrPopover').text().replace(/\s\s+/g, '');
        const numReviews = $('#centerCol #acrCustomerReviewText').text().replace(/\s\s+/g, '');
        const prodImg = $('#landingImage').attr('data-old-hires');

        console.log("productTitle", productTitle);
        console.log("price", price);
        console.log("rating", rating);
        console.log("numReviews", numReviews);
        console.log("prodImg", prodImg)
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks to be the remedy. What's weird is this was working without the gzip enabled to true before. Not sure why. Guess I'll have to RTFM on request later. Thanks jfriend00!

Comment: @VI11age_ID10T - My theory is that Amazon changed their default page compression to something that `request()` doesn't support so you have to request GZIP in the request now.

Comment: After being in request hell for a lot longer than i cared for i switched over to axios